# PHP Use Latest Revision From Database

Tags: php, sql

I have a value in my database called `revision` which increases when there's a duplicate entry.

I'm trying to select the latest revision in my database. Example:

```
|-----------------------------|
| Title            | Revision |
|-----------------------------|
| Some title 1     | 0        |
| Some title 1     | 1        |
| Some title 1     | 2        | <-- select this one
|-----------------------------|
```

This is my query (just for example, I know the last argument will fail):

```
$titlecheck = $this->query("SELECT * FROM titles WHERE tmdb_name=:name AND tmdb_titleid=:skuid AND revision=:revision");
if($titlecheck->execute(array(":name" => $api[1]['tmdb']['name'], ":skuid" => $api[1]['tmdb']['titleid'], ':revision'=>LARGEST))) {
    // do something
}
```

How can I select the latest revision number? I have looked into `MAX()` but since I'm required to select all from the database I won't be able to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ORDER` to ensure certain order of returned rows. Otherwise you may get it in random order:

```
SELECT * FROM titles 
WHERE tmdb_name=:name AND tmdb_titleid=:skuid
ORDER BY revision DESC
```

then the first row will be the one with highest Revision. If you need just that, use `LIMIT 1` at the end of query and ensure `revision` column has index.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the argument revision if you want the latest revision

```
SELECT * FROM titles WHERE tmdb_name=:name AND tmdb_titleid=:skuid
order by revision desc limit 1;
```